# Equivalence of continuity conditions of a group representation on an infinite-dimensional space

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be an (infinite-dimensional) Banach space and $G$ a locally compact topological group (with a countable basis of neighbourhoods of
$1$, and which is a countable union of compact subsets). I want to understand the proof of the following lemma, namely that the following are equivalent:

(1) the map $\pi: G \times V \to V$ is continuous, that is: $\forall g \in G \:  \forall v \in V \: \forall \varepsilon > 0$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $1$ in $G$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $\|\pi(x g) (v+u) - \pi(g)v\| < \varepsilon$ whenever $\|u\| < \delta$ and $x \in X$.

(2) the following two conditions hold:

(i) for all $v \in V$ the map $G \to V$, $g \mapsto \pi(g)v$ is continuous, that is, for all $v$ we have: $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ there exists a neighbourhood $X$ of $1$ in $G$ such that $\|\pi(x)v-v\| < \varepsilon$ whenever $x \in X$.

(ii) if $X$ is a compact subset then for all $v$: $\|\pi(x)v\| \leq \|v\|$ ($x \in X$)

Now I see $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$, since (i) and (ii) follow from (1) by specialization. For the other direction let $g \in G$, $v \in V$. Then writing
$\|\pi(xg)(v+u)-\pi(g)v\| \leq \|\pi(x)\pi(g)v - \pi(g)v\|+\|\pi(x)\pi(g)u\|$
I see that the first term gets small by assumption (i) (put $\tilde v = \pi(g)v$) and the second term should get small by assumption (ii) but dont I only get $\|\pi(x)\pi(g)u\| \leq \|\pi(g)u\|$, how does it follow that this is smaller than $\|u\|$?

Edit/Addon: What is the relation of (2)(ii) with equicontinuity of the family $\{\pi(x): x \in X\}$? (sorry if this question is naive, but I still struggle to see through all the definitions and their meaning)

Comment: If you look at (2)(ii), the RHS does not depend on $X$ in any way. Doesn't it follow, since $G$ is a countable union of compact subsets, that $||\pi(g)v||\leq ||v||$ for all $g\in G$?

Comment: but then i dont understand the formulation of (ii). The neighbourhood basis is a countable union of compact sets. I dont think this implies the group is a countable union of compact sets. And why would it imply that the RHS of (ii) is valid for all $x \in G$?

Comment: Actually, i think one can simply translate a neighbourhood of the $1$ in $G$ to a ngh of $g$